# RecyclerView button item clickListener and LongPressClickListener combine in TouchListener android

Tags: android-recyclerview, android-view, ontouchlistener

I have a recyclerView with several view types. One of those is an EditText with a button. This editText shows a Number which represents number of months and the Button next to it is used to increase the value. The user can either click on the Button to increase by one month or longPress (with a startUp delay as default) and keep it pressed in order to start auto-increase the value of the editText (let's say 4 values per second) and stop increasing when button released.

```
binding.buttonPlus.setOnClickListener {
    incrementValue(binding.textQuantity, item, eventHandler)
}
```

The onBind method has already a clickListener, however i want to add the longPress functionality but without effect the clickListener functionality. I believe this is possible to happen with onTouchListener. Is there anybody that knows how that could be implemented?